# Coreldraw X3: Add a macro on to the toolbar

Tags: macros, toolbar, coreldraw

I use a macro all the time via Tools->Visual Basic->Play.

Does anybody know how I can add this macro on to the toolbar?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

1. Start CorelDRAW X3
2. Create or open a document
3. Open `Tools`->`Options` menu
4. Select `Customization` on the left, click the dropdown box under `Commands` and select `Macros`
5. Find your macro and drag'n'drop it onto any toolbar to insert or onto an empty space to create a new toolbar with just this macro button.
6. You can also customize the hotkey and `Appearance` of the icon in the corresponding tab on the right (be sure to select image size matching the toolbar's size or simply choose the same image for both sizes).

See an [illustrated step-by-step tutorial](http://woxxom.vbabyexample.com/installtutor/installtutor.html).